# PHP recursive function not returning expected

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
use app\models\Kategorije;

function hasMoreParent($id,$i = 0){
    $model = new Kategorije();
    $parent_id = $model::find()->where('id = :id',[':id' => $id])->one()->parent_id;
    if ($parent_id > 1) {
        $i++;
        hasMoreParent($parent_id,$i);
    }
        return $i;
}
```

And, if $i is greater than 0 it always returns 1 instead of 2 or 3.. 
How can I make it to return those other numbers?

Comment: you never capture the return values of the recursive calls, so at the top-level, you'll only ever get the FIRST call's value returned. you probably want `$i += hasMoreParent(...)` instead.

Comment: Can you write the example @MarcB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the return keyword in order to achieve the recursion, otherwise the function `hasMoreParent` will be executed, but the flow will continue and reach the `return $i;` statement.

```
use app\models\Kategorije;

function hasMoreParent($id, $i = 0) {
    $model = new Kategorije();
    $parent_id = $model::find()->where('id = :id', [':id' = > $id])->one()->parent_id;
    if ($parent_id > 1) {
        $i++;
        return hasMoreParent($parent_id, $i);
    }
    return $i;
}
```

Comment: You, sir, have just saved my life! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! glad to help :)